# mod_fcgid windows named pipes 2nd and subsequent requests

Tags: c, windows, pipe, named

All, I'm building a fastCGI interface for a programming language which is run-time based, and runs in Windows, Linux and UNIX environments.

I've implemented the fastCGI protocol within program code that runs within that run-time but I'm having an issue with Windows code which talks to mod_fcgid. In this case I cannot use prebuilt dll's to expose fastCGI functions, but I can make calls to most C functions from within that runtime language. I cannot modify the runtime as it belongs to another company... Think of it as being a php or perl like language. What I'm trying to do is similar to creating a dll like set of code (its not a dll) to process a fastCGI request. While many would say I'm "re-inventing the wheel" here, I have no choice of using someone's prebuilt dll to provide the interface to fastCGI.

I've successfully implemented everything and I can get the initial request, and respond back with a web page thru my fastCGI interface. The problem I am having is dealing with the "next" request when running under Windows. My code when running under Linux works terrific, I accept() the socket, read() write() to do my processing, close() the socket, and then go back and accept() again, and I get the next request and everything processes perfectly.

Under Windows mod_fcgid uses named pipes. Within my code I use GetStdHandle() to get a handle to stdin, then use ReadFile() and WriteFile() and the data wrapped in the fastCGI protocol goes to mod_fcgid and then on to the browser when done with a request I use CloseHandle() and then am looping back to GetStdHandle() to wait for the next request.

Everything works perfectly for the first request, the browser gets my cgi output. The same code under Linux using sockets, gets the 2nd and subsequent requests and works like a charm.

My issues is: when running under Windows, after I process the first request, I cannot get mod_fcgid to send me a second request. It will end up killing my windows process and starts a new one in its place. Which of course is not what I want.

I must being doing something wrong between the time I send the fastCGI EndRequest and when I loop around to wait for the next request to come in.

To get the initial request from mod_fcgid, I use GetStdHandle() then I use ReadFile() and WriteFile() (all from kernel32.dll) and when I've finished the protocol with its EndRequest, I cannot get the code right to be able to receive a second request.

I've tried fflush() I've tried FileFlushBuffers(), I've tried not closing the handle I was given from GetStdHandle(), I simply cannot figure out what mod_fcgid needs from my windows app so that I can receive the second and subsequent requests.

After the first request, closing my handle, getting a handle to stdin from GetStdHandle, and then sitting on ReadFile, The ReadFile() comes back with 0 bytes, and GetLastError() always returns 6 (Invalid Handle).

I simply cannot figure out the C functions to use to cleanup after the first request is complete and to be able to wait for the next request to come in when running under Windows. As I've said before the code works perfect under Linux when using sockets instead of Windows which is using a handle from STDIN that is a named pipe.

Comment: Do you mean, it uses _un_named pipes? That's what I would expect when `STDIN/STDOUT` is used.

Comment: I can't find any documentation to confirm this, but based on how the FastCGI protocol works over TCP/IP I would expect that the handle you've been given is to the *server* end of the named pipe.  (My previous comment, now deleted, assumed that it was the client end; my mistake.)  So instead of closing the handle, you want to call DisconnectNamedPipe followed by ConnectNamedPipe (which will block until a new request is ready).

Comment: Harry, thanks for that. I do believe I need to use those NamedPipe functions. I've been pouring through the source for mod_fcgi which includes the libfcgi.dll that people can use to include in their apps. I see it using the ConnectNamedPipe and DisconnectNamedPipe, As well it's using some IOCompletion that I don't really understand what it is used for, but I believe your right about the NamedPipe calls. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harry, your comment on using the NamedPipe functions did the trick, I needed to use FileFlushBuffers followed by a DisconnectNamedPipe at the end of the first request, and then a ConnectNamedPipe to wait for the next request to come in. Thank you again.